# Fortran calls: advantage of passing by pointer vs passing by reference

Tags: pointers, fortran

It is my understanding that in Fortran arrays are passed by reference. So is there an advantage to passing a pointer to a large array (into a subroutine) as opposed to passing the array itself.

Could you also clarify this in the context of recursive functions. I have seen implementations where pointers are used "for efficiency", but if everything is passed by reference, then what's the benefit of pointers.

Here's an example. I have an array X (in reality lets say it's a very large array).

```
INTEGER :: X(:)
```

I can define a subrouitne that takes this array as follows:

```
SUBROUTINE FOO(X)
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: X(:)

    INTEGER :: I

    DO I = 1, 4
        WRITE(*,*) X(I)
   ENDDO
END SUBROUTINE FOO
```

When I call the subroutine above then the array X is not copied as fortran passes a reference to it. Now lets say I have a modified version of the subroutine:

```
SUBROUTINE FOO2(X)
    INTEGER, POINTER, INTENT(IN) :: X(:)
    INTEGER :: I

    DO I = 1, 4
        WRITE(*,*) X(I)
   ENDDO
END SUBROUTINE FOO2
```

I can call `FOO2` from a program as follows:

```
PROGRAM TEST
IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER, TARGET :: X(5)
INTEGER, POINTER :: Y(:)

X = (/1,2,3,4,5/)
Y => X

CALL FOO2(Y)
END PROGRAM TEST
```

Then here's my question: is there a performance difference between the two versions of foo? Is there any useful scenario where the declaration of FOO2 might be preferable to FOO?

Comment: You appear to be pretty confused. Do you mean Fortran pointer variables or just addresses? Passing by reference and passing a pointer is on machine code level or C language level (almost) the same. Show us example of your two approaches, your description is definitely not sufficient. Voting to close for now.

Comment: Pointers, what are pointers ?  I'm a Fortran programmer.  And what do you mean by *as opposed to passing the array itself* ?  Right now I'm tending to agree with @VladimirF (I usually do) and can't see how your question, as phrased, could draw forth good answers.

Comment: @VladimirF I am not confused, but i can be more clear. I do mean pointer variables (I don't know what else can one mean by pointers in the context of fortran, so i don't see the origin of any confusion). I simply want to understand if there is a difference between passing an array X to a subroutine and passing a pointer declared to the target X to that subroutine from an efficiency point of view. I should also add that you shouldn't down vote questions just because you don't understand what is being asked. Just ask for clarification.

Comment: Edit your question and insert an example. BTW I didn't downvote you, just voted to close, but the rules are different, you can downvote whatever you think is not useful here. This also concerns excessively hard to understand questions.

Comment: Don't forget to specify if you mean a scalar or an array. Whether it is a single argument or there are more of them. Whether the non-pointer array argument is assumed shape or assumed size/explicit size. Whether you work with any other variables from the host or use association that have the `target` attribute. It can all mean a lot.

Comment: Okay Vladimir I've added an example.

Comment: If you declare a dummy variable "pointer" the subroutine can change its association status. The compiler is also forbidden from assuming it is unaliased. Don't do it if you don't need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this simple case there shouldn't be any real difference. Note the program is illegal, you don't have the explicit interface to `FOO` or `FOO2`, but I will assume you just ommited it for simplicity and they are in a module or internal.

Both arrays can be non-contiguous in principle, so no difference here. If that slows down the code, the `contiguous` attribute might help. Or assumed size or explicite size arrays too.

Your subroutine is too simple, so there is no danger of aliasing too. This is the common source of decreasing performance with pointers. There could be potential aliasing with some other argument or another variable you access by host or use association provided it has the `target` attribute.

The purpose of pointer arguments is actually to either allow disassociated (`null()`) arguments, or to allow changing of the association status in the subroutines. Your example doesn't use neither and therefore the pointer attribute is superfluous.

There is on last small difference. It is not specified in the standard what is actually passed to the subroutine at the machine code level for the pointer variables. If it is just an address (likely for scalars) it is the same as non-pointer, just the aliasing rules and the allowed usage are different. Otherwise some descriptor is passed, but any overhead should be negligible, the assumed shape arrays use a descriptor too.